# Java: Can't get incremented value to print.

Tags: java, string, int, println

I'm learning to do some Java 101 syntax stuff. In an exercise I'm trying to do, I can't get the incremented value to print. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
class StaticTest { 
    static int i = 47;  
}
class incrementable { 
    static void increment() { StaticTest.i++; } 
}

class DataOnly { 

    int i;
    double d;
    boolean b; 

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        incrementable t = new incrementable(); 
        DataOnly df = new DataOnly(); 
        df.i = t.increment(); 
        System.out.println(df.i);
    } 

}
```

The error I get is:

```
aTyp0eName.java:18: incompatible types
found: void 
required: int 
df.i = t.increment();
```

`df.i` is an `int` and so is `t.increment`.  I'm guessing it's because `increment()` is `void`?

Comment: To fit in with other classes, increment should be renamed incrementAndGet (as it appear to be attempting to return the value before the increment). If it were to use pre-increment (which is more natural), the name should be getAndIncrement. Side-effects are nasty.

Answer (score 4):

`increment()` doesn't have a return value.  You'd need to have it return an `int` for your code to work:

```
class incrementable { 
    static int increment() { 
        StaticTest.i++;
        return StaticTest.i;
    } 
}
```

"`void`" is a keyword reserved for methods which don't return any value.  Otherwise, you specify what class or primitive you return (`int`, `double`, `String`, whatever).  You can read more about return values [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Also, for future reference, class names should be capitalized, so you should be using "Incrementable" rather than "incrementable".  (In my sample code I kept it the same as you had it so you could just drop the code in for now.)

Comment: If  you return i++, you'll get the value before it was incremented.  Probably not what he wanted.

Comment: Because you need "return" to return a value from a method.  That's just the way Java works.

Comment: @phill: Because i++ first uses the current value and then increments the variable. In this case, it puts the value in the "return" value of the method. To increment before use "return ++StaticTest.i;"

Answer (score 4):

your method signature is:

```
static void
```

Which means nothing is returned from this method.

Hence, attempting to assign `increment()` to `df.i` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the increment() method returns a void. That being said, there are a lot of violations of the Java standard syntax that programmers generally use, Namely:

1. Class names should start with a capital letter.
2. fields should not be mutated from different classes, rather a helper method should be within the same class
3. If you want to call a static method, don't reference an instance variable, rather use ClassName.reference
4. If a variable is only needed locally, it should not be a field (df.i could just be an int i declared within the main method).

EDIT:
An example of a helper method within the same class:

```
class StaticTest { 
    private static int i = 47; //keep i private and mutate and access via methods
    public static void increment() { i++; }
    public static int getI() { return i; }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on #2--more specifically what would be an example of a helper method?

Answer (score 2):

> *The error I get is:*

```
aTyp0eName.java:18: incompatible types
found: void 
required: int 
df.i = t.increment();
```

> *df.i is an int and so is t.increment [fault?]. I'm guessing it's because increment() is void?*

Eeeexactly, your guess is correct.

This is the error message explained line by line:

```
aTyp0eName.java:18: incompatible types
```

You are trying to assign "void" to an int in line 18.

```
df.i = t.increment();
```

Here is where the error is.

```
found: void
```

You declare what's the return type in the method "signature".
The method signature is :

```
<access modifiers> <return type> <method name> (<parameters> )
static                 void       increment        ()
```

So the return type is void.

Next line:

```
required: int
```

df.i is int as you have previously stated.

So, pretty much you have already your own question answered.

The good point of having a compiler is that it tells you when something is wrong.

The bad thing ( for humans ) you have to learn to read those messages.  They vary from programming language to another and even from compiler to compiler.

This would be a corrected version:

```
class StaticTest { 
    static int i = 47;  
}
class Incrementable { 
    static int increment() { 
        return ++StaticTest.i;
    } 

}

class DataOnly { 

    int i;
    double d;
    boolean b; 

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        Incrementable t = new Incrementable(); 
        DataOnly df = new DataOnly(); 
        df.i = t.increment(); 
        System.out.println(df.i);
    } 

}
```

There are some other enhancements could be done, such as adding access modifiers to the methods and attributes, but for now I think this would help.

Answer (score 0):

also, if you instantiate incrementable, you shouldn't define the method increment() as static. or you can, but don't need to.

you could simply incrementable.increment() if it's static.

just a tip. as for the answer to your question, toolkit already said that right.

Answer (score 0):

Also, your `incrementable` class should really be `Incrementable`.

Comment: is there a reason why it is capitalized?

Comment: Just code convention, makes reading "easier"  http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/index.html

Comment: @phill: Easier to differentiate between types and variables. All ( hopefully ) the java source code you'll see follows this convention. Also method names start with lower case and all names ( except for constants ) use camelCase.